# selectOneRadio with null value not displaying correctly (Mojarra 2.1.28)

Tags: jsf, el

I have a Boolean that is set with a selectOneRadio tag as follows:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.someBoolean}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="false" itemLabel="No"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Not applicable"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

It correctly passes these values to the bean, but it behaves strangely when displaying these values. If the Boolean is true, it correctly selects the 'Yes' radio button. If the Boolean is false, however, it selects the "Not applicable" button and if the Boolean is null, it selects nothing at all. I've tested it with `<h:selectOneMenu>` and that works perfectly fine. What's going on here?

Comment: Any one have any luck with this?